# Why are these subrepresentations of the permutation representation of $S_4$ acting on the faces of the cube?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I have been given an example of a subrepresentation as follows,

> Let V be the permutation representation of $S_4$ acting on the
> faces of the cube. Remember that we can see a vector in V as a way of
> writing a complex number on each face. Then we can spot three subrepresentations:
>
>  • the subrepresentation where the numbers on all faces are equal
>
> • the subrepresentation where the numbers on opposite faces sum to
> zero
>
> • the subrepresentation where the numbers on opposite faces are equal
> and all the labels sum to zero.

How are are the second and third examples subrepresentations?

To my understanding, a subrepresentation is a subset such that whenever the group action acts on any element of the subset, the element produced is still a member of this same subset. Yet, for instance in the second case, would it not be possible to permute the faces of the cube so that the numbers on opposite faces do not sum to zero? As an explicit example, if we were to label the faces of the cube as an ordinary die, we could have $(1, 2, 3, -3, -2, -1)$ as the numbers corresponding to face $1$, face $2$, face $3$, face $4$, face $5$ and face $6$ respectively. The numbers of opposite faces would then sum to zero. We could permute this to $(1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3)$, and then the numbers on opposite faces would not all sum to zero. There must be something that I have misunderstood, but I am not entirely sure what it is.

Comment: You'll have to explain your "example" more carefully: as far as I know when the group acts on the cube it sends any pair of opposite faces to a pair of opposite faces.

Comment: @Muddled by Maths: It is best to set the dollar-signs around S_4 completly, and not just _4, this butchers your text. :)

Comment: The group of rotations of the cube is isomorphic to $S_4$. This group has $24=4!$ elements. When $S_4$ acts on the cube's faces, it is permuting the faces by rotating the cube. No amount of rotating the cube can cause two opposite faces to become adjacent, or cause adjacent faces faces to become opposite. If we could permute the 6 faces freely, we would have the permutation group $S_6$ with $6!=720$ permutations, not $S_4$ with $4!=24$ permutations.

Comment: @Cornman Okey dokey, noted - thanks! :)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Oh I see! That's rather cleared things up - thank you :)